# reset formik when the route changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

So I'm using formik in a react component, and I want to reset the formik whenever a route changes.
my solution is to use useEffect like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
formik.resetForm();
}, [location]);
```

the problem is that I'm getting this error:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'formik'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps

so when I'm trying to add Formik as a dep to the array I'm getting:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

I don't want to turn off the eslint warning for this line but I don't know how to solve it.
any suggestions?

thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `formik` changes, you run `resetForm()`, which causes a render, and a new `formik` object, which causes a reset...

Destructure `resetForm` out of the `formik` object:

```
const { resetForm } = formik;

useEffect(() => {
  resetForm();
}, [location]);
```